# closed planar curves invariants

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/generique/generique.shtml

In this french website, he presents an invariant of closed planar curves: number of double points.

He says that there is no curves with 1 or 2 double points.

But how many double points for the eight shape curve or the limacon curve ?

Comment: No, it says there are no **irreducible** curves with $1$ or $2$ double points.

Comment: He /she says there are no *irreducible* curve with $1$ or $2$ double points. And it is noted the lemniscate  (the name of the eight-shaped curve) or the limaçon with a double point are not irreducible in the sense he /she gives.